# WordPress: Category sort by Latest Post Date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, themes, categories

I am working in a custom WP theme.I need to show each posts under individual categories, which is working fine.But, i want to sort the categories according to the published date of posts.

I found one answer, but its not working in my code and i cant figure how to use it in my code.So, i need anyone's expert help/input in below code.
[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689315/wordpress-category-sort-by-date)

```
     **<?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',

    ) );

    foreach($terms as $cat){
        $cata_name = $cat->name; 
        $term_id = $cat->term_id; 
        $catqueryy = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$term_id.'&posts_per_page=10');$count = $catqueryy->found_posts;while($catqueryy->have_posts()) : $catqueryy->the_post();?>    


                        <div class="list-group">
                            <p class="post_excerpt">
                            <?php echo ' <a  href="'.home_url('index.php/category/'.$cata_name).'">'.__(get_the_title(),'rockon').'</a>'; ?>  
</div>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to show all categories by date

```
    <?php $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'ID',
    'order'              => 'DESC',
); ?>
 <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestions but i want to sort all the categories . Your code will show the categories in a list..i want to show all categories with posts...